# Adding jquery library files in my GSP page

Tags: jquery, grails, fullcalendar

How to import plugin css and JS files in GSP page? I am having plugins.jquery=1.7.1
plugins.jquery-ui=1.8.1 and want to link it to my FullCalendar GSP page so that I can link Jquery calendar to FullCalendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the line for the jQuery plugin :

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

to the **layout** as mentioned [here](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery) and this for jQuery UI :

```
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
```

If you need to add custom js add it like

```
<script src="${resource(dir: 'js/misc', file: 'filename.js')}" />
```

in your gsp page.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in the following way.
Place your jquery file(filename.js) into inside web-app/js directory and 
write the command in your gsp main page as below:

```
<g:javascript src="filename.js"/>
```

hope this helps,
Rubel.